# how to use the <draggable> to drag a group of elements in vue

Tags: vue.js

so first heres my data in my script

```
   upperTableHeaders: [
        ["Participants", 15],
        ["Game of Choice", 10],
        ["Performance", 15],
        ["Budget", 60],
      ],

      tableHeaders: [
        "Names",
        "Language",
        "Country",
        "Game",
        "Bought",
        "Balance",
        "Rating",
        "Winnings",
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
      ],
```

my template is as such

```
 <table class="table custom-table">
      <thead class="sticky-headers">
        <tr>
          <draggable
            class="upperTable"
            v-model="upperTableHeaders"
            :options="{ handle: '.handle' }"
            :style="{ width: `${tableWidth}px` }"
            @end="updateUpperTableHeaders"
          >
            <th
              class="handle"
              v-for="header in upperTableHeaders"
              :key="header[0]"
              :style="{ width: `${header[1]}%` }"
            >
              {{ header[0] }}
            </th>
          </draggable>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <draggable v-model="tableHeaders" :options="{ handle: '.handle' }">
            <th
              class="handle"
              v-for="header in tableHeaders"
              :key="header"
              @click="onClickHeader(header)"
            >
              {{ header }}
              <input
                class="search-input"
                v-model="searchQuery[header]"
                type="text"
                @click.stop
              />
              <span v-if="sortOrder[header] === 'asc'">&#x25B2;</span>
              <span v-if="sortOrder[header] === 'desc'">&#x25BC;</span>
              <span v-if="sortOrder[header] === null"></span>
            </th>
          </draggable>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <draggable
          class="data-table"
          v-model="tableData"
          :options="{ handle: '.handle' }"
        >
          <tr class="handle" v-for="item in filteredTableData" :key="item.id">
            <td class="handle" v-for="header in tableHeaders" :key="header">
              {{ item[header.toLowerCase()] }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I'm building is essentially an excel spread sheet on crack, so use that for the image in your head. The upperTableHeaders array is 4 headers that span across the width of the data sheet. Underneath each of these headers is a group of columns.

Underneath "Participants" is "Names", "Language, "Country".

Underneath "Game of Choice" is "Game", and "Bought".

Underneath "Performance" is "Balance", "Rating, "Winnings".

Underneath "Budget" are the 12 remaining months.

These are all set up in a perfect grid. What I want is when you drag Participants column to the right or left along the row, you also drag the corresponding headers and data underneath. Any help is appreciated

I tried using the .group setting on the `<draggable>` component but that didn't work. I've been at this for hours totally stumped. I am wondering if somehow I'm setting up my data structures wrong.

If I change the v-model class from "upperTableHeaders" to "tableHeaders" like so

```
            <draggable
            class="upperTable"
            v-model="tableHeaders"
            :options="{ handle: '.handle' }"
            :style="{ width: `${tableWidth}px` }"
            @end="updateUpperTableHeaders"
          >
```

I can end up dragging the first of each upperTableHeader, tableHeader, and its corresponding data, only because its on the same v-model. Im new to vue but whats bothering me is that the v-model can only be used once and is only a two way connection. So I am wondering if restructing my data is the way to go..

Comment: Can you send a screenshot example of what the table is currently look like? You can upload the screenshot here. https://imgbb.com/ Thanks!

Comment: Sure! here you go https://ibb.co/SNfypJR

Comment: @ReaganM and here is another screenshot with a border: 1px red solid grid outline so you get the outline https://ibb.co/kG5pkXc

right now the rows drag up and down, and the lower columns drag left and right, dragging the data with it, so names can drag right and the names will drag with it etc.

Comment: I'll try to investigate as I am also using vue draggable.  Last question, was the other question you posted is fixed? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701483/how-to-get-th-elements-to-align-with-tr-and-td-elements

Comment: @ReaganM Yes I solved that. I'm thinking it may have to do with my datastructures and how its set up